# How Can I Write and Run a Django User Registration Unit Test Case

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django Project that contain two apps; account and realestate and I have a user registration form for registration. This Registration Form is working correctly on my local machine but I want to write and run a Django Unit test for it to be sure everything is working internally well.
Below is my Registration Form code:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Define the user_type choices
USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('landlord', 'Landlord'),
    ('agent', 'Agent'),
    ('prospect', 'Prospect'),
)

# Create the registration form
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control left-label'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control left-label'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control left-label'}))
    user_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES, widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control left-label'}))
   
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2', 'user_type']
```

Here is my User Registration View code:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Create a new user object
            user = form.save()
            # Get the user_type value from the form
            user_type = form.cleaned_data['user_type']
            # Create a new object based on the user_type
            if user_type == 'landlord':
                Landlord.objects.create(user=user)
            elif user_type == 'agent':
                Agent.objects.create(user=user)
            elif user_type == 'prospect':
                Prospect.objects.create(user=user)
            # Log the user in and redirect to the homepage
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('success-account')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    context =  {
        'form': form,
        'page_title': 'Register',
        }
    return render(request, 'account/register.html', context)
```

Here is my Unit Test Code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.urls import reverse
from account.forms import RegistrationForm
from realestate.models import Landlord, Agent, Prospect

class RegisterViewTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.url = reverse('register-account')

    def test_register_view_success(self):
        data = {
            'username': 'testuser',
            'email': 'testuser@example.com',
            'password1': 'testpassword',
            'password2': 'testpassword',
            'user_type': 'landlord'
        }
        form = RegistrationForm(data)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())
        response = self.client.post(self.url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('success-account'))

        user = User.objects.get(username='testuser')
        self.assertIsNotNone(user)
        self.assertTrue(user.check_password('testpassword'))

        landlord = Landlord.objects.get(user=user)
        self.assertIsNotNone(landlord)

    def test_register_view_invalid_form(self):
        data = {
            'username': 'testuser',
            'email': 'testuser@example.com',
            'password1': 'testpassword',
            'password2': 'wrongpassword',
            'user_type': 'landlord'
        }
        form = RegistrationForm(data)
        self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
        response = self.client.post(self.url, data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'account/register.html')

        form = response.context['form']
        self.assertTrue(form.has_error('password2'))

        user_exists = User.objects.filter(username='testuser').exists()
        self.assertFalse(user_exists)
```

Any time I run **python manage.py test account.tests.RegisterViewTestCase** on the terminal error says: **ERROR: RegisterViewTestCase (unittest.loader._FailedTest), AttributeError: module 'account.tests' has no attribute 'RegisterViewTestCase'**.
What could be the issue here and how can it be fixed.

Comment: Follow [This](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/) tutorial my brother.

Answer (score 1):

The error say that the test are not found within the 'account' package.

You need to check if your test file is properly named, for instance:

- tests.py

or

- test_register.py

and run `$ ./manage.py test` this

check django documentation from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/overview/):

> The default startapp template creates a tests.py file in the new
> application. This might be fine if you only have a few tests, but as
> your test suite grows you’ll likely want to restructure it into a
> tests package so you can split your tests into different submodules
> such as test_models.py, test_views.py, test_forms.py, etc. Feel free
> to pick whatever organizational scheme you like.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that test file starts with test_*.py or if the tests file in test folder create **init**.py within the folder